# Получение данных из строки в Generics Java

Tags: java, строки, generics

Есть ли какая-нибудь возможность создать метод, который превратит строку в необходимое значение нужного типа. Предполагаю использовать типы `Float`, `String`, `Short`. Желаю нечто вроде этого:

```
public MyObject(T value, int a) {
  //...//
}

public static <T> MyObject getMyObjectFromLine(String line) {
    return new MyObject<T>(???, 42);
}
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, можно ли значение параметра `line` подставить в generic?

Comment: @AntonMaximov, да.

Comment: Нет, этого сделать нельзя. Generics есть только на этапе компиляции, всё должно быть "жёстко зафиксировано" в написанном коде. Во время исполнения эта информация теряется.
Расскажите подробнее, зачем вам здесь generic.

Comment: `MyObject` имеет свойство `value`, которое, очевидно, бывает разным по типу. Также, объект должен воссоздаваться из строки (поскольку желаю хранить эдакую "базу" таких объектов в txt) с этим параметром (ключевой в общем-то). Объект содержит и несколько иных деталей. Однако, `T` сам по себе лишь притив или строка.

Comment: Можно завести `enum Type` со значениями `INTEGER`, `FLOAT`, `STRING`. Потом делаете `Type.valueOf(line)` и у вас есть значение типа. Можно, конечно, делать и `Class.forName(className)`, чтобы получить именно класс, но в вашем случае это кажется избыточным.

Comment: Вы уверены? Мне необходимо именно присвоить (передать в конструктор) значение строки нужного типа (аля передать Float). Вашим образом я получу лишь название типа, что не совсем соответсвует задаче. @AntonMaximov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
public class MyVal<T> {

    private T val;

    public MyVal(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public static <T> MyVal getMyObjectFromLine(String value, String type) {
        switch (Type.valueOf(type)) {
            case STRING:
                return new MyVal<>(value);
            case INTEGER:
                return new MyVal<>(Integer.parseInt(value));
            case FLOAT:
                return new MyVal<>(Float.parseFloat(value));
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected type: " + type);
        }
    }
}
```